# Can hindu men wear an earing to work?

Tags: rituals

I want to use it but people say it's against office policy and only for cultural reasons we can. Could somebody give me some advice on what shall I do?

Comment: by earing you mean big one or the small one normally what pandits refer to? Btw why does your office object to it? Really absurd. But this question is more of an opinion deemed not fit for the forum.

Comment: is there any hindu custom that says that a man can wear an earing?

Comment: you can get more info from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnavedha

Comment: thank you, i will wear it, i just need some text to prove that it is apart of my religion

Comment: not sure if that link helped you but check this out as well for more proof :) http://www.sanskritimagazine.com/rituals_and_practices/ear-piercing-in-hinduism/

Comment: Going to office is also against hindu dharma. There is no such stage in the four ashramas.

Comment: @Parikshitha I beg to differ, if you don't work how do you support yourself & your family? And where does it say?

Comment: @Just_Do_It in the present materialistic world, one has to do any job even if he is not eligible to do that. But as per vedic dharma, one should do the duties based on their varna.

Comment: @Parikshitha I agree with that, so as Brahmin went to collect alms, vaishayas went to trade, kashatriyas went to war & shudras did their tasks, in a way they all were going to a specific work place now termed as office. No? You can't do everything from your home.

Comment: @Just_Do_It But it looks like going to office is dharma of Vaishya